# How do I change the default phone number?

Tags: contacts

The phone is a Galaxy S 2.2.  I set up the phone for my wife using my SIM card.  Now she is using the phone with her own SIM card, but the phone still displays my phone number in the system settings and sends SMS as my number.  There seems no way to remove this number.

- We have edited the profile in contacts.
- We factory reset the phone.
- We have removed my number from contacts.

So far our first Android experience is very disturbing as too many aspects are blocked. There seems no way to remove the registered number in the phone system.

Comment: Have you tried asking your service provider?

Comment: Perhaps you've already tried this but have you tried assigning a different gmail account to the phone than the one originally used?

Comment: [This topic](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3072/in-my-samsung-galaxy-s-under-settings-status-phone-number-is-says-unknown/3074#3074) might help.

Comment: I second Gary's suggestion.  Unless you unlock the phone, you probably shouldn't be switching SIMs without help from the carrier.  Also, what Galaxy S model do you have?

Answer (score 1):

I constantly switch SIM cards between a few of my Android phones and have never seen this issue come up. As far as I am aware, the phone gets the information on the phone number from the SIM card directly.

A SIM card (short for Subscriber Identity Module) is what holds the information such as the phone number and the information to activate it on your providers network. You mention when she sends text that your number shows up. "Cloning" a phone number is not easily possible (if at all) so you definitely need to contact your service provider as they should be able to shed some light on what's going on with your SIM.

Not that this makes a difference, but if you remove the SIM, turn the phone on and go to your system settings and the number should be gone. This will show you that the phone gets the info from the SIM and not stored in the phone anywhere.

I'm sorry to hear that your first Android experience has not gone well, but I'm fairly confident that this is an issue with your SIM/Provider and not the phone itself.

Comment: This happens when you take your old number to a new provider's SIM. The SIM still has the provider's original number on it.