# Change own phone number in ICS

Tags: samsung-nexus-s, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I've change the SIM in my Galaxy-Nexus-S. Under `Settings -> About phone -> Status` there still is the old phone number and I cannot manage to change it.

I've seen [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3072/in-my-samsung-galaxy-s-under-settings-status-phone-number-is-says-unknown/3074#3074) which is outdated. The menu option `Own numbers` discribed in the answer is not there in ICS.

<sub>The navigation terms might be called differently, as I manually translated the names from German.</sub>

Comment: The way I had to do it in Gingerbread was to put the SIM into a Blackberry, change the number there, and then it updated when I put the SIM back into my Nexus S. (The number isn't always stored on the SIM, so if it isn't then Android won't update - you need to manually story it, which AFAIK you can't do on ICS/Gingerbread, hence the Blackberry method)

Answer (score 1):

In previous versions of Android (mine is 2.3.7) you can set this setting in the *Additional call settings*. In Android 4.0 the Additional call settings screen is located here:

Open the **Phone** app -> [Menu] -> **Settings** -> **Additional settings**.

I have not verified this on a physical device yet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately there is no option to change the phone number here.

Comment: @gentmatt It's there for me.

Answer (score -1):

You need to reprogram the phone.  Dial ##786# on the dial pad and then hit view.  You may need your MSL to be able to change the phone number.

Comment: "Connection problem or invalid MMI code."

Comment: @Mr. Monkey "UNKNOWN APPLICATION" is what i get. Are you sure there is not supposed to be additiona # at the end?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried just a factory reset?  Sounds like you got a new phone, right?  Any opposition to just wiping and starting fresh?  I would think that would do it.

Comment: Ever since I got ICS 4.0.3 on my Nexus S, I had to wipe it twice already :)