# HTC Desire S - Number Unknown Is Shown?

Tags: sim-card, dialer-codes

My question is similar **[to this one](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3072/in-my-samsung-galaxy-s-under-settings-status-phone-number-is-says-unknown)**, however what would be appropriate solution for HTC Desire S device because it does not allow you to change your phone number on SIM card like Samsung Galaxy does? Here is what it looks like on my phone (sorry for bad focus):

[image]

Here are other topics with same problem:

http://miuiandroid.com/community/threads/desirehd-my-phone-number-unknown-please-read.6002/

http://www.htcsensationforum.com/troubleshooting-htc-sensation-4g/phone-number-unknown/

http://androidcommunity.com/forums/f8/my-phone-number-39390/

Comment: possible duplicate of [In my Samsung Galaxy S under Settings - Status - Phone number is says 'unknown' : why?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3072/in-my-samsung-galaxy-s-under-settings-status-phone-number-is-says-unknown)

Comment: Did you try the solution(s) in the other question?  You need to explain why this question is different.

Comment: Because my device is HTC Desire S and not Samsung Galaxy S. There is no option to change or set number.

Answer (score 6):

The bad news is that some phones (like yours) don't support setting your own phone number. The good news is that this information is not stored on your phone but on your sim card.

So if you put your sim in another device and set your number there than you can put it back to your phone and voila, your number will show.

Some devices that support setting your phone number:

- Apple iPhone (Be aware that newer versions have microSIM slots!)
- Samsung Galaxy series (Read [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3072/in-my-samsung-galaxy-s-under-settings-status-phone-number-is-says-unknown) on how to do it)
- All ICS devices ([Info](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/18474/13391))
- Some custom roms (Including CyanogenMod)
- Some Sony Ericsson dumbphones (e.g: C902, K550i)

If you don't have access to any of the above you can ask your carrier to do it. It is possible that they can do it OTA.

Comment: Some suggestions of phones that do allow the changing of the number could be helpful here.

Comment: I tried with Motorola dumbphone, had options of setting 4 personal numbers, set all 4 with same number but HTC Desire S still showed "Unknown".

Comment: @Boris_yo that sets numbers on the phone not on the SIM. Try it with an iPhone or  Samsung galaxy. Those are the only ones where I've seen this setting without custom ROM. CyanogenMod supports this too.

Comment: @Boris_yo updated with some devices and an option to have your carrier do it.

Comment: @RichardBorcsik Tried **##786#** but got "Unknown Application". Do you think there supposed to be additional # at the end?

Comment: @Boris_yo the ics link was for the answer above that, not for the one with the code. That doesn't work either on 2.3 or 4.0. Have you tried calling your carrier? It might be your best bet if you can't get access to a phone that can set it.

Comment: This answer is very old and I'm considering asking again because it is outdated. I suspect that contacting the carrier is the only method, but in my case, I can't contact the carrier directly. I have asked my provider to contact the carrier. My provider said the phone# was supposed to update automatically within 90 days of service, but I've had my SIM in service for 5 months already.

Answer (score 1):

this happens on some network sims because they do not store the number onto the sim.

You can add the number to the sim by using a device that allows you. These devices normally do:

- Older (non smart) devices
- Most custom roms
- ICS Devices
- iPhone (below ios 5)
- Some other stock roms