# Unknown phone number issue

Tags: sim-card

My Moto X with Android kit Kat does not recognize my own number from the Sim card. Is there a way to edit it manually? Any app that does that?

Comment: You might want to take a look at these questions: [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/21225/30530) and [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/3072/30530)

Comment: None of the solutions presented in those answers works for me. I guess nothing will do.

Answer (score 0):

from moto support

> If the contacts are not backed up with Gmail, back them up.
>
> Clear cache/data on Dialer, Contacts and Contacts Storage (for the latter, make sure the contacts are backed up in Gmail)
>
> Log into Gmail on a PC > Contacts > More > Merge Duplicates > Restore
>
> Edit one of the contacts that keeps appearing as unknown. In the phone number, add spaces (ex: 07894561234 would become 0789 456 1234)
>
> Try another SIM from another network.
>
> Try with only one active SIM (the second SIM can be disabled in Settings > Dual SIM settings)
>
> Select the Network Manually in Settings > More > Mobile Networks > Network Operators

the last one helped me

Comment: Can you link the source(s)?

Comment: now, its from email. byt it works for me

Answer (score -1):

the best way to solve this issue... its rlly just borrowing someone's phone and insert your sim card and edit phone number to solve this issue.

Comment: You should edit your answer to explain how this would be done.